# Angular 9 "ng build --prod" with Devextreme failing only on Jenkins

Tags: node.js, angular, jenkins, npm, devextreme

Our Jenkins job fails since the update to Angular 9. Everything works from the command line when logged in at the build server as the builduser. It also works on other devices in the command line.
But when the Jenkins job runs, the script `ng build --prod`fails

The error message is:

```
[33mWarning:[0m Entry point 'devextreme-angular/ui/vector-map' contains deep imports into 'C:/Users/builduser/.jenkins/workspace/my_project-Angular9/node_modules/devextreme/viz/vector_map', 'C:/Users/builduser/.jenkins/workspace/my_project-Angular9/node_modules/devextreme/bundles/dx.all'. This is probably not a problem, but may cause the compilation of entry points to be out of order.
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
npm info lifecycle my_project@1.0.30~build: Failed to exec build script
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 134
npm ERR! my_project@1.0.30 build: `ng build --prod`
npm ERR! Exit status 134
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the my_project@1.0.30 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm timing npm Completed in 161871ms

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\builduser\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-14T15_05_03_975Z-debug.log
```

The Devextreme warnings at the beginning also appear on the successfull builds on our local machines, so I'm not sure if this is really a problem or if they can be ignored.

NodeJS version is 12.16.1 and NPM version is 6.13.4 on all machines.

The complete log mentioned mentioned above:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\builduser\\.jenkins\\tools\\jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation\\node12\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\builduser\\.jenkins\\tools\\jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation\\node12\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.13.4
3 info using node@v12.16.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle my_project@1.0.30~prebuild: my_project@1.0.30
6 info lifecycle my_project@1.0.30~build: my_project@1.0.30
7 verbose lifecycle my_project@1.0.30~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle my_project@1.0.30~build: PATH: C:\Users\builduser\.jenkins\tools\jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation\node12\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\builduser\.jenkins\workspace\my_project-Angular9\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\builduser\.jenkins\tools\jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation\node12;C:\Users\builduser\.jenkins\tools\jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation\node12;C:\Bitnami\rubystack-2.4.5-7\ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Resource Kits\Tools\;C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.4;C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv;C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v7.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\bin;C:\Users\alisakarolina.becker\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Python27;C:\Users\builduser\gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.5-bin\36tjdrrafkua0yehaomoqzk6f\gradle-4.5\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Gpg4win\..\GnuPG\bin;C:\Program Files\doxygen\bin;C:\Maven\apache-maven-3.6.1\bin;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin;C:\Tools\sonar-scanner-4.2.0.1873-windows\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\builduser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\builduser\Documents\gradle\gradle-4.5\bin;C:\Tools\CppDepend;C:\Program Files\Cppcheck;C:\Tools\Process Explorer
9 verbose lifecycle my_project@1.0.30~build: CWD: C:\Users\builduser\.jenkins\workspace\my_project-Angular9
10 silly lifecycle my_project@1.0.30~build: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'ng build --prod' ]
11 silly lifecycle my_project@1.0.30~build: Returned: code: 134  signal: null
12 info lifecycle my_project@1.0.30~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: my_project@1.0.30 build: `ng build --prod`
13 verbose stack Exit status 134
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\builduser\.jenkins\tools\jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation\node12\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:311:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\builduser\.jenkins\tools\jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation\node12\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid my_project@1.0.30
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\builduser\.jenkins\workspace\my_project-Angular9
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.14393
17 verbose argv "C:\\Users\\builduser\\.jenkins\\tools\\jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation\\node12\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\builduser\\.jenkins\\tools\\jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation\\node12\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v12.16.1
19 verbose npm  v6.13.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 134
22 error my_project@1.0.30 build: `ng build --prod`
22 error Exit status 134
23 error Failed at the my_project@1.0.30 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 134, true ]
```

The Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  tools {nodejs "node12"}

  stages {

    stage('install dependencies') {
      steps {
        bat 'npm install --no-save'
      }
    }

    stage('build version') {
      steps {
        bat "npm run build"
      }
    }
}
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my_project",
  "version": "1.0.30",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^9.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "^9.1.1",
    "@angular/elements": "^9.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.1.1",
    "@angular/material": "^9.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "^9.1.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "^9.1.1",
    "compass-mixins": "^0.12.10",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "dateformat": "^3.0.2",
    "devextreme": "^19.2.7",
    "devextreme-angular": "^19.2.7",
    "devextreme-intl": "^19.1.8",
    "in-view": "^0.6.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "muuri": "0.8.0",
    "ng2-nouislider": "^1.8.2",
    "nouislider": "^14.1.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^1.11.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "9.1.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "^9.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "9.1.1",
    "@types/dateformat": "^3.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.5.9",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.6",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.33",
    "@types/node": "^13.9.1",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "^4.0.9",
    "clang-format": "^1.0.32",
    "css-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "cypress": "^3.8.3",
    "del": "^5.1.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "file-loader": "^5.1.0",
    "fs-extra": "^8.1.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^3.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-typescript": "^4.1.1",
    "lodash.throttle": "^4.1.1",
    "ng-annotate-webpack-plugin": "^0.3.0",
    "ng-focus-if": "^1.0.7",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "node-sass-json-importer": "^4.1.2",
    "pre-commit": "^1.2.2",
    "properties-loader": "0.0.1",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "script-loader": "^0.7.2",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "ts-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "ts-node": "^8.0.0",
    "tslint": "^6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.5",
    "watch": "^1.0.2",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.6.1"
  }
}
```

The "build" script works if the "--prod" parameter is removed

angular.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "my_project": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "rc",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "aot": true,
            "outputPath": "dist/my_project",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "8mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "my_project:build",
            "aot": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "my_project:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "my_project:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.ts",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
  },
  "defaultProject": "my_project"
}
```

Has anybody some idea what the reason of this error could be?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this?

Comment: unfortunately, no

Comment: Does this work on a development machine? Or anyother machine?

Comment: It works on other machines and even in the command line on the build server, but not in the Jenkins pipeline.

Comment: did you anythink about that ?